# How to setup a MIDI Keyboard? - Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: sound, wine, midi

I have a MIDI Keyboard - Alesis QX49, which is compatible only 
with Windows and Mac. A Disc of Ableton Live came with the keyboard. 
(I've managed to install Ableton using Wine).
Qsynth and QJackCtl are installed by default. 
I've been trying to setup the keyboard with these tools, 
with no success.

What should I do?

Thank you.

UPDATE: Output of lsusb -v (I didn't know which one is the right one, sorry for the length)

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Couldn't open device, some information will be missing Device Descriptor: bLength 18 bDescriptorType 1 bcdUSB 3.00 bDeviceClass 9 Hub bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused bDeviceProtocol 3 bMaxPacketSize0 9 idVendor 0x1d6b Linux Foundation idProduct 0x0003 3.0 root hub bcdDevice 4.04 iManufacturer 3 iProduct 2 iSerial 1 bNumConfigurations 1 Configuration Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 2 wTotalLength 31 bNumInterfaces 1 bConfigurationValue 1 iConfiguration 0 bmAttributes 0xe0 Self Powered Remote Wakeup MaxPower 0mA Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 0 bAlternateSetting 0 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 9 Hub bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 3 Transfer Type Interrupt Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0004 1x 4 bytes bInterval 12 bMaxBurst 0

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e360 Atheros Communications, Inc. Couldn't open device, some information will be missing Device Descriptor: bLength 18 bDescriptorType 1 bcdUSB 2.01 bDeviceClass 224 Wireless bDeviceSubClass 1 Radio Frequency bDeviceProtocol 1 Bluetooth bMaxPacketSize0 64 idVendor 0x0cf3 Atheros Communications, Inc. idProduct 0xe360 bcdDevice 0.01 iManufacturer 0 iProduct 0 iSerial 0 bNumConfigurations 1 Configuration Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 2 wTotalLength 177 bNumInterfaces 2 bConfigurationValue 1 iConfiguration 0 bmAttributes 0xe0 Self Powered Remote Wakeup MaxPower 100mA Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 0 bAlternateSetting 0 bNumEndpoints 3 bInterfaceClass 224 Wireless bInterfaceSubClass 1 Radio Frequency bInterfaceProtocol 1 Bluetooth iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 3 Transfer Type Interrupt Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0010 1x 16 bytes bInterval 1 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x82 EP 2 IN bmAttributes 2 Transfer Type Bulk Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0040 1x 64 bytes bInterval 1 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x02 EP 2 OUT bmAttributes 2 Transfer Type Bulk Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0040 1x 64 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 0 bNumEndpoints 2 bInterfaceClass 224 Wireless bInterfaceSubClass 1 Radio Frequency bInterfaceProtocol 1 Bluetooth iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0000 1x 0 bytes bInterval 1 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x03 EP 3 OUT bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0000 1x 0 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 1 bNumEndpoints 2 bInterfaceClass 224 Wireless bInterfaceSubClass 1 Radio Frequency bInterfaceProtocol 1 Bluetooth iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0009 1x 9 bytes bInterval 1 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x03 EP 3 OUT bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0009 1x 9 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 2 bNumEndpoints 2 bInterfaceClass 224 Wireless bInterfaceSubClass 1 Radio Frequency bInterfaceProtocol 1 Bluetooth iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0011 1x 17 bytes bInterval 1 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x03 EP 3 OUT bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0011 1x 17 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 3 bNumEndpoints 2 bInterfaceClass 224 Wireless bInterfaceSubClass 1 Radio Frequency bInterfaceProtocol 1 Bluetooth iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0019 1x 25 bytes bInterval 1 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x03 EP 3 OUT bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0019 1x 25 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 4 bNumEndpoints 2 bInterfaceClass 224 Wireless bInterfaceSubClass 1 Radio Frequency bInterfaceProtocol 1 Bluetooth iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0021 1x 33 bytes bInterval 1 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x03 EP 3 OUT bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0021 1x 33 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 5 bNumEndpoints 2 bInterfaceClass 224 Wireless bInterfaceSubClass 1 Radio Frequency bInterfaceProtocol 1 Bluetooth iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0031 1x 49 bytes bInterval 1 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x03 EP 3 OUT bmAttributes 1 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0031 1x 49 bytes bInterval 1

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller Couldn't open device, some information will be missing Device Descriptor: bLength 18 bDescriptorType 1 bcdUSB 2.00 bDeviceClass 255 Vendor Specific Class bDeviceSubClass 255 Vendor Specific Subclass bDeviceProtocol 255 Vendor Specific Protocol bMaxPacketSize0 64 idVendor 0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp. idProduct 0x0129 RTS5129 Card Reader Controller bcdDevice 39.60 iManufacturer 1 iProduct 2 iSerial 3 bNumConfigurations 1 Configuration Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 2 wTotalLength 39 bNumInterfaces 1 bConfigurationValue 1 iConfiguration 4 bmAttributes 0xa0 (Bus Powered) Remote Wakeup MaxPower 500mA Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 0 bAlternateSetting 0 bNumEndpoints 3 bInterfaceClass 255 Vendor Specific Class bInterfaceSubClass 6 bInterfaceProtocol 80 iInterface 5 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x01 EP 1 OUT bmAttributes 2 Transfer Type Bulk Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0200 1x 512 bytes bInterval 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x82 EP 2 IN bmAttributes 2 Transfer Type Bulk Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0200 1x 512 bytes bInterval 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN bmAttributes 3 Transfer Type Interrupt Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0003 1x 3 bytes bInterval 10

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57f9 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Couldn't open device, some information will be missing Device Descriptor: bLength 18 bDescriptorType 1 bcdUSB 2.00 bDeviceClass 239 Miscellaneous Device bDeviceSubClass 2 ? bDeviceProtocol 1 Interface Association bMaxPacketSize0 64 idVendor 0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp. idProduct 0x57f9 bcdDevice 0.06 iManufacturer 3 iProduct 1 iSerial 2 bNumConfigurations 1 Configuration Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 2 wTotalLength 751 bNumInterfaces 2 bConfigurationValue 1 iConfiguration 4 bmAttributes 0x80 (Bus Powered) MaxPower 500mA Interface Association: bLength 8 bDescriptorType 11 bFirstInterface 0 bInterfaceCount 2 bFunctionClass 14 Video bFunctionSubClass 3 Video Interface Collection bFunctionProtocol 0 iFunction 5 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 0 bAlternateSetting 0 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 14 Video bInterfaceSubClass 1 Video Control bInterfaceProtocol 0 iInterface 5 VideoControl Interface Descriptor: bLength 13 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 1 (HEADER) bcdUVC 1.00 wTotalLength 107 dwClockFrequency 15.000000MHz bInCollection 1 baInterfaceNr( 0) 1 VideoControl Interface Descriptor: bLength 18 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 2 (INPUT_TERMINAL) bTerminalID 1 wTerminalType 0x0201 Camera Sensor bAssocTerminal 0 iTerminal 0 wObjectiveFocalLengthMin 0 wObjectiveFocalLengthMax 0 wOcularFocalLength 0 bControlSize 3 bmControls 0x00000004 Auto-Exposure Priority VideoControl Interface Descriptor: bLength 11 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 5 (PROCESSING_UNIT) Warning: Descriptor too short bUnitID 2 bSourceID 1 wMaxMultiplier 0 bControlSize 2 bmControls 0x0000147f Brightness Contrast Hue Saturation Sharpness Gamma White Balance Temperature Power Line Frequency White Balance Temperature, Auto iProcessing 0 bmVideoStandards 0x 9 None SECAM - 625/50 VideoControl Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL) bTerminalID 3 wTerminalType 0x0101 USB Streaming bAssocTerminal 0 bSourceID 6 iTerminal 0 VideoControl Interface Descriptor: bLength 27 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 6 (EXTENSION_UNIT) bUnitID 4 guidExtensionCode {8ca72912-b447-9440-b0ce-db07386fb938} bNumControl 2 bNrPins 1 baSourceID( 0) 2 bControlSize 2 bmControls( 0) 0x00 bmControls( 1) 0x06 iExtension 0 VideoControl Interface Descriptor: bLength 29 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 6 (EXTENSION_UNIT) bUnitID 6 guidExtensionCode {5a10b826-1307-7048-979d-da79444bb68e} bNumControl 3 bNrPins 1 baSourceID( 0) 4 bControlSize 4 bmControls( 0) 0x00 bmControls( 1) 0x00 bmControls( 2) 0x00 bmControls( 3) 0x07 iExtension 7 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x83 EP 3 IN bmAttributes 3 Transfer Type Interrupt Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0010 1x 16 bytes bInterval 6 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 0 bNumEndpoints 0 bInterfaceClass 14 Video bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming bInterfaceProtocol 0 iInterface 0 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 15 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 1 (INPUT_HEADER) bNumFormats 2 wTotalLength 485 bEndPointAddress 129 bmInfo 0 bTerminalLink 3 bStillCaptureMethod 1 bTriggerSupport 1 bTriggerUsage 0 bControlSize 1 bmaControls( 0) 11 bmaControls( 1) 11 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 11 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 6 (FORMAT_MJPEG) bFormatIndex 1 bNumFrameDescriptors 7 bFlags 1 Fixed-size samples: Yes bDefaultFrameIndex 1 bAspectRatioX 0 bAspectRatioY 0 bmInterlaceFlags 0x00 Interlaced stream or variable: No Fields per frame: 1 fields Field 1 first: No Field pattern: Field 1 only bCopyProtect 0 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG) bFrameIndex 1 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 1280 wHeight 720 dwMinBitRate 442368000 dwMaxBitRate 442368000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 1843200 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG) bFrameIndex 2 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 160 wHeight 120 dwMinBitRate 9216000 dwMaxBitRate 9216000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 38400 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG) bFrameIndex 3 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 320 wHeight 240 dwMinBitRate 36864000 dwMaxBitRate 36864000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 153600 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG) bFrameIndex 4 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 640 wHeight 360 dwMinBitRate 110592000 dwMaxBitRate 110592000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 460800 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG) bFrameIndex 5 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 640 wHeight 480 dwMinBitRate 147456000 dwMaxBitRate 147456000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 614400 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG) bFrameIndex 6 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 800 wHeight 600 dwMinBitRate 230400000 dwMaxBitRate 230400000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 960000 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG) bFrameIndex 7 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 1280 wHeight 720 dwMinBitRate 442368000 dwMaxBitRate 442368000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 1843200 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 6 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 13 (COLORFORMAT) bColorPrimaries 1 (BT.709,sRGB) bTransferCharacteristics 1 (BT.709) bMatrixCoefficients 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601)) VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 27 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED) bFormatIndex 2 bNumFrameDescriptors 7 guidFormat {59555932-0000-1000-8000-00aa00389b71} bBitsPerPixel 16 bDefaultFrameIndex 1 bAspectRatioX 0 bAspectRatioY 0 bmInterlaceFlags 0x00 Interlaced stream or variable: No Fields per frame: 2 fields Field 1 first: No Field pattern: Field 1 only bCopyProtect 0 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED) bFrameIndex 1 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 1280 wHeight 720 dwMinBitRate 147456000 dwMaxBitRate 147456000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 1843200 dwDefaultFrameInterval 1000000 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 1000000 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED) bFrameIndex 2 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 160 wHeight 120 dwMinBitRate 9216000 dwMaxBitRate 9216000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 38400 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED) bFrameIndex 3 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 320 wHeight 240 dwMinBitRate 36864000 dwMaxBitRate 36864000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 153600 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED) bFrameIndex 4 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 640 wHeight 360 dwMinBitRate 110592000 dwMaxBitRate 110592000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 460800 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED) bFrameIndex 5 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 640 wHeight 480 dwMinBitRate 147456000 dwMaxBitRate 147456000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 614400 dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED) bFrameIndex 6 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 800 wHeight 600 dwMinBitRate 115200000 dwMaxBitRate 115200000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 960000 dwDefaultFrameInterval 666666 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 666666 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 30 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED) bFrameIndex 7 bmCapabilities 0x01 Still image supported wWidth 1280 wHeight 720 dwMinBitRate 147456000 dwMaxBitRate 147456000 dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 1843200 dwDefaultFrameInterval 1000000 bFrameIntervalType 1 dwFrameInterval( 0) 1000000 VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor: bLength 6 bDescriptorType 36 bDescriptorSubtype 13 (COLORFORMAT) bColorPrimaries 1 (BT.709,sRGB) bTransferCharacteristics 1 (BT.709) bMatrixCoefficients 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601)) Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 1 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 14 Video bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming bInterfaceProtocol 0 iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 5 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type Asynchronous Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0080 1x 128 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 2 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 14 Video bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming bInterfaceProtocol 0 iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 5 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type Asynchronous Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0200 1x 512 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 3 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 14 Video bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming bInterfaceProtocol 0 iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 5 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type Asynchronous Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0400 1x 1024 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 4 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 14 Video bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming bInterfaceProtocol 0 iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 5 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type Asynchronous Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0b00 2x 768 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 5 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 14 Video bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming bInterfaceProtocol 0 iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 5 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type Asynchronous Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0c00 2x 1024 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 6 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 14 Video bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming bInterfaceProtocol 0 iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 5 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type Asynchronous Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x1380 3x 896 bytes bInterval 1 Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 1 bAlternateSetting 7 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 14 Video bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming bInterfaceProtocol 0 iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 5 Transfer Type Isochronous Synch Type Asynchronous Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x1400 3x 1024 bytes bInterval 1

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Couldn't open device, some information will be missing Device Descriptor: bLength 18 bDescriptorType 1 bcdUSB 2.00 bDeviceClass 9 Hub bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused bDeviceProtocol 1 Single TT bMaxPacketSize0 64 idVendor 0x1d6b Linux Foundation idProduct 0x0002 2.0 root hub bcdDevice 4.04 iManufacturer 3 iProduct 2 iSerial 1 bNumConfigurations 1 Configuration Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 2 wTotalLength 25 bNumInterfaces 1 bConfigurationValue 1 iConfiguration 0 bmAttributes 0xe0 Self Powered Remote Wakeup MaxPower 0mA Interface Descriptor: bLength 9 bDescriptorType 4 bInterfaceNumber 0 bAlternateSetting 0 bNumEndpoints 1 bInterfaceClass 9 Hub bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub iInterface 0 Endpoint Descriptor: bLength 7 bDescriptorType 5 bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN bmAttributes 3 Transfer Type Interrupt Synch Type None Usage Type Data wMaxPacketSize 0x0004 1x 4 bytes bInterval 12

Comment: Show the output of `lsusb -v` for this device.

Comment: I added the output as an update.

Comment: The keyboard does not show up. It's possible that the firmware tries to detect whether the host runs Windows or OS X, and gets confused. Please show what appears in the system log when you plug it in. (It appears the QX49 [is not the only Alesis device with this problem](http://community.alesis.com/alesis/topics/alesis-q25-no-data-connection).)

Comment: It doesn't appear in the system logs for some reason

Comment: But do you see something in the log when other USB devices are plugged in?

Comment: dbus[1047]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Mar 19 00:22:11 n systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Mar 19 00:22:11 n dbus[1047]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Mar 19 00:22:11 n systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.